# winwait not catching "message from webpage"

Tags: message, html, autohotkey

I'm trying to use autohotkey to acknowledge an website's timeout message and keep the session alive automatically.  Winwait seems like the ideal function for this, but for some reason it's not doing what I think it should be doing.

Here is the function I wrote that is not working:

```
  DetectHiddenWindows, On
  SetTitleMatchMode 2
  winwait, Message from webpage, Your TrackWise session is expiring
    ControlClick, Button1, Message from webpage, Your TrackWise session is expiring
  return
```

The window is a popup from internet explorer.  Here is what the window spy tells me about the window I want to detect and automatically click OK on:

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
Message from webpage
ahk_class #32770

>>>>>>>>>>>>( Mouse Position )<<<<<<<<<<<<<
On Screen:  1503, 692  (less often used)
In Active Window:   1219, 259

>>>>>>>>>( Now Under Mouse Cursor )<<<<<<<<

Color:  0xF0F0F0  (Blue=F0 Green=F0 Red=F0)

>>>>>>>>>>( Active Window Position )<<<<<<<<<<
left: 284     top: 433     width: 484     height: 174


>>>>>>>>>>>( Status Bar Text )<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>( Visible Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<
OK
Cancel
Your TrackWise session is expiring in 15 minute(s). 
If you would like to continue click OK, otherwise you will be logged off TrackWise.

>>>>>>>>>>>( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Hidden Text )<<<<
```

For whatever reason, winwait isn't getting it.  If I use a hotkey like this:

```
#k::ControlClick , Button1, Message from webpage, Your TrackWise session is expiring
```

Then win+k clicks the right button, keeps the webpage session alive like I want, just not automatically like I want.

Any suggestions?  Thank you!!!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that with IE10. I tested with a [sample page](http://jsfiddle.net/9zxhG/) mimicking the popup, and your code (just the `WinWait`). It immediately finds the window upon creation. Does WinWait detect the popup on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

```
titleOption:="ahk_exe iexplore.exe ahk_class #32770", GW_OWNER:=4
Loop
{
   WinWait, % titleOption
   WinGet, procName, ProcessName
         , % "ahk_id "DllCall("GetWindow", "Ptr", hWnd:=WinExist(titleOption)
                                         , "UInt", GW_OWNER
                                         , "Ptr")
   If % procName=="IEXPLORE.EXE"
      ControlClick, % "Button1", % "ahk_id "hWnd
   Sleep, 250
}
```